# Проверка входа на сайт

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, сервлеты

Здравствуйте. Ниже представлен код

```
@WebServlet(name = "SignInServlet", urlPatterns = {"/SignInServlet"})
public class SignInServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String login = req.getParameter("login");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    String role;

    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

    Connection conn = null;

    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/crm";
    String name = "vladimir";
    String pass = "1234";
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, pass);
        Statement statement = null;
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,conn.toString());
        ResultSet result1 = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
        while (result1.next()) 
        {
            if((password.equals(result1.getString("password"))) && 
                    (login.equals(result1.getString("login"))))
            {
                role = result1.getString("userrole");
                getServletContext().
                        getRequestDispatcher("/signiinsucces.jsp").
                        forward(req, resp);
            }
            /*else if((!password.equals(result1.getString("password"))) && 
                    (!login.equals(result1.getString("login"))))
            {
                getServletContext().
                        getRequestDispatcher("/signiinfail.jsp").
                        forward(req, resp);
            }*/
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        getServletContext().
                getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").
                forward(req, resp);
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (conn != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                conn.close();
            } 
            catch (SQLException ex) 
            {
                getServletContext().
                        getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").
                        forward(req, resp);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Как можно осуществить проверку для входа, чтобы успешном входе отправляло на страничку signiinsucces.jsp, а при неудачной попытке на signiinfail.jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу строго не судить этот код с моего первого приложения по Java.

Я реализовал для своего учебного приложения проверку вошел или нет по кукам. 
Вначале делаю проверку в куках стоит ли метка авторизации, если нет то проверяю логин и пароль, и если ни один из перечисленных вариантов не прошел вывожу сообщение об ошибке и перенаправляю на страницу ввода логина и пароля.
Для лишения прав на доступ достаточно очистить куки от метки авторизации.

Так же я не давно узнал что существует легковесная библиотека для авторизации Apache Shiro https://shiro.apache.org/ , на любом проекте рекомендуют не писать самостоятельно авторизацию, а использовать готовое решение.

@WebServlet("/admin")
public class Admin extends HttpServlet {

```
private static final String LOGIN = "admin";
private static final String PASSWORD = "admin";

private static final String cookieName = "ADMIN";
private static final String cookieValue = "ADMIN";



@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

    String login = req.getParameter("login");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");

    int a = LOGIN.compareTo(login);
    int b = PASSWORD.compareTo(password);
    System.out.println("a = " + a);
    System.out.println("b = " + b);

    // проверяет вход по защита ли авторизация в куках
    if (Util.isLoginSuccessful(req)) {
        resp.sendRedirect("/dbservlet");

    // если не зашиты данные в куках то проверяет введенный логин и пароль   
    } else if (Util.isCorrectLoginPassword(req)) {
        // здесь в куках прописываем метку авторизации
        resp.addCookie(new Cookie(cookieName, cookieValue));
        // перенаправляем на на servlet который отвечает за завешенную 
        // страницу, где так же будет проверка на авторизацию через куки
        resp.sendRedirect("/dbservlet");

    } else {
        // если никакой способ авторизации не прошел выводи сообшение
        // об ошибке и через 5 секунд перенаправляет на страницу авторизации
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("Incorrect login or password");
        resp.setHeader("Refresh", "5;URL=http://localhost:8080/admin.html");
    }
}

// метод проверяет метку в куках
public static boolean isLoginSuccessful(HttpServletRequest req) {
    Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().contains(cookieName) && cookie.getValue().contains(cookieValue)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Напишите о результатах.